# SOBO Authentication does not put envelope in docusign account

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using SOBO authentication using legacy header described here:  https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/sobo.html.  I send an envelope to user1 on behalf of user2.  The envelope is sent successfully to user1.  However when I log into docusign as user2 and go to Manage > Sent, I do not see the envelope that was sent to user2.  I also tried envelope status = created and I do not see the envelope in user2's Manage > Drafts.

Any ideas why the envelope is not showing up appropriately in the docusign account for the SOBO user?

Comment: Can you please share the Auth Header which you are using for sending/creating the envelopes, as SOBO is working fine for me. Also now DocuSign (https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html) does not recommend to use Legacy Auth Header, instead you should use Service Integration Authentication as explained here, https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html

Comment: @AmitKBist  X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"ff0a489b-24e9-4f96-90f3-ba037d6cf268", "Password":"XXXXXXX", "IntegratorKey":"b00058a4-67ef-49ed-9f3f-a9125a7e0ec7", "SendOnBehalfOf":"testemail@mail.com"}

Comment: Does your userId ff0a489b-24e9-4f96-90f3-ba037d6cf268 has permission   "apiAccountWideAccess" and "allowSendOnBehalfOf" set as true. In the New DocuSign Admin experience, these settings are in the the Permission Sets section as Allow view and manage envelope rights through API and Allow send on behalf of other users through API. These settings are on by default for the DS Admin permission set.

In the Classic DocuSign Admin experience, you can find these settings in the Member Options section as Account-Wide Rights and Send On Behalf Of Rights (API).

Comment: That was it.  Thanks @AmitKBist

Comment: Let me put it as answer so that others get benefit out of it. Please accept it as an answer

Comment: @AmitKBist Actually I was wrong.  Still an issue.  Got my sobo email mixed up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159402/discussion-between-los-morales-and-amit-k-bist).

Answer (score 0):

userId ff0a489b-24e9-4f96-90f3-ba037d6cf268 needs to have permissions "apiAccountWideAccess" and "allowSendOnBehalfOf" set as true. In the New DocuSign Admin experience, these settings are in the the Permission Sets section as Allow view and manage envelope rights through API and Allow send on behalf of other users through API. These settings are on by default for the DS Admin permission set. In the Classic DocuSign Admin experience, you can find these settings in the Member Options section as Account-Wide Rights and Send On Behalf Of Rights (API). Also check if you are using correct account to see the draft or sent envelopes.

Comment: Actually I was wrong.  This still does not work for me.  Still an issue.  Got my sobo email mixed up